# React axios interceptor does not call defined function

Tags: reactjs, axios

Hello I am using axios interceptor to centralize errors in the application. I am using redux to call functions and display a success or error toast but when I call the function in the interceptor the function 'is not called displaysuccess function is not called

```
import AuthentificationService from "./AuthentificationService";
import {displayError} from '../store/actions/errorActions
import {displaySucces} from '../store/actions/succesActions

api.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
   displaySucces(response.status);
   //fonction no trigger
  return Promise.resolve(response);
}, function (error) {
  displayError(error.response.status)

  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Comment: Dieu you try to dispatch your action: dispatch(displaySuccess(response)) ?

Comment: Thank you very much nicolas  its displayed now but the function is executed twice. So I have the same toast twice how to fix it. Thank you really

Comment: Without knowing what the rest of your code does it's difficult to answer, you should check what your actions do